# Spring MVC SessionAttribute not initialized in all controllers (Spring Boot 1.4.2)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've got a strange behavior with a SessionAttribute.
I've defined a SessionAttribute named nafSelection to be used in 2 controllers: NafController and StatsController.

When I pass through the NafController, the SessionAttribute is created and the StatsController can use it. If first, I use the StatsController I've got an error "Missing session attribute 'nafSelection' of type NafSelection".

For sharing the model attribute I've coded a ControllerAdvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice('com.dyndata.sirene.controllers')
class ModelAdvice {
    @ModelAttribute("nafSelection")
    NafSelection newSelection() {
        new NafSelection()
    }
}
```

And I declare the session attribute in my 2 controllers:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("nafSelection")
class NafController {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NafController.class.name);

    @RequestMapping('/naf')
    def naf() {
        'naf'
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = '/naf/{nafCode}', method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    def affNafCode(@PathVariable String nafCode, @SessionAttribute NafSelection nafSelection) {
        logger.info("Adds the NAF " + nafCode)
        nafSelection.nafs << nafCode

        return new Counter(count: 5600)
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = '/naf/{nafCode}', method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    def delNafCode(@PathVariable String nafCode, @SessionAttribute NafSelection nafSelection) {
        logger.info("Deletes the NAF " + nafCode)
        nafSelection.nafs.remove(nafCode)

        return new Counter(count: 80000)
    }
}
```

The second controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("nafSelection")
class StatsController {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StatsController.class.name);

    @RequestMapping(path = '/stats')
    def stats(@SessionAttribute NafSelection nafSelection) {
        'stats'
    }
}
```

Why the session attribute is well managed by the NafController and not by the StatsController?

Note: My code is in Groovy language.

Answer (score 0):

I've found :)

I must mark the method parameter as ModelAttribute instead of SessionAttribute.